# How can I move an image from one folder to another folder?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3, image-uploading

I use Laravel 5.3

When I upload image, I save the image in :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\storage\temp

My code to save the image like this :

```
private function addPhoto(UploadedFile $photo, $fileName)
{
    $destinationPath = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'temp';
    $photo->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    return $fileName;
}
```

When I click button submit, I want to move the image from folder storage to folder public

So I want to move the image in :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img

How can I move the image in folder public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `rename` function.
Try something like that:

```
$org_image="C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\storage\temp\xxxx.jpg";
$destination="C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img";

$img_name=basename($org_image);

if( rename( $org_image , $destination.'/'.$img_name )){
 echo 'moved!';
} else {
 echo 'failed';
}
```